# NSUserDefaults refuse to save

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Start a new single view project and update the main ViewController's viewDidLoad. The intention is to retrieve and increment a value stored in `NSUserDefaults` and save it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *key = @"kTheKey";

    NSNumber *number = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"current value is %@", number);

    NSNumber *incremented = @(number.integerValue + 1);
    NSLog(@"new value will be %@", incremented);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:incremented forKey:key];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    NSLog(@"reboot");
}
```

If I force quit the app from Xcode (or in practical use, reboot the device), the defaults are frequently not saved. Here is some sample output:

```
current value is (null)
new value will be 1
reboot
current value is 1
new value will be 2
reboot
current value is 1
new value will be 2
reboot
```

There appears to be some time component - if I wait 3+ seconds before rebooting, it is more likely the defaults will save. Note that the first execution was 'allowed' to save by waiting for a few seconds before stopping execution. The second execution was stopped in the first second or two, leading to the unchanged values logged in the the third run. This is re-produceable on my iPad Air 2 running iOS 8.1.

What could account for this?

Comment: Are the last 3 lines of the log actually just copy paste of the previous 3?

Comment: Yes, I had trouble copying and pasting the content without exceeding the time component I mentioned.  I will remove the timestamps to avoid confusion.

Comment: Will it happen on device? I don't think so.

Comment: The code looks OK and `NSUserDefaults` should persist across reboots. But see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2622754/558933 . Also, is there some reason you are not using `integerForKey` and `setInteger:forKey`?

Comment: I just wrote an answer which stated that you should synchronize in applicationWillTerminate but then I realized that you're already synchronizing, so that might not be the issue...

Comment: The first 6 lines of your log look to me like what you're expecting, right? As @Wain asked, are those last three actually from a subsequent run of the app?

Comment: According to an engineer who improved the iOS 8 synchronize function at Apple, "On iOS 8 the delay after calling -[NSUserDefaults set*:forKey:] before the value is safely stored is about 1ms." (https://twitter.com/catfish_man/status/510122371995299840) so I don't know what's causing the issue yet, but "synchronize" should hypothetically make little difference...

Comment: @LyndseyScott: I believe the `-synchronize` call will always forcibly flush anything yet unwritten, so as soon as it returns you can assume the data is on disk. My guess is that David Smith's comment means that iOS 8 makes an explicit synchronization less necessary because it's now so fast without.

Comment: @BenZotto Yes, I'm saying that the 3 sec delay the OP is observing might be unrelated to synchronize. Something else might be going on. Or there could potentially be a bug if the function's in flux...

Comment: @LyndseyScott: Ah, I see. Yes, I agree-- the OP's code looks fine.

Comment: @BenPackard Your code works perfectly for me.

Comment: @LyndseyScott - are you stopping execution from XCode (command-.) quickly enough? Stop the app as soon as the console logs. I'm testing on an iOS 8.1 iPad fwiw.

Comment: @BenZotto - yes, that's what I'm expecting. The first execution I allowed to save by not quitting for a few seconds. The second execution, I quit immediately (or within 1-2 seconds) to demonstrate the inconsistent nature of the issue.

Comment: @gabbler - yes, I am testing this on a device. an iPad Air 2 running iOS 8.1 to be specific.

Comment: @BenPackard Yes, I'm quitting immediately. I added `exit(0);` right after `NSLog(@"reboot");` and everything prints as expected.

Comment: @LyndseyScott thanks for trying it. Did you run on a device? Which? I will start testing whether I can get the same behavior on some other devices.

Comment: @BenPackard Hm... You're right. I originally ran it on a simulator and got the expected results, but I just tried it on my device and it's not always saving. Bug perhaps?

Comment: @RoboticCat check my code - I am already calling `synchronize`. The link you suggest is not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behavior.

User defaults get queued to save. When you "force quit" the app you're not giving it time to do that.

I assume that on Xcode you mean hitting stop. And you mention exit(0);.  Neither of things are "normal" to an iOS app.  This type of force quitting should not be done in an iOS app.

When the user quits an app the normal way (multi-task view and sliding the app up) it doesn't actually quit right then. It removes from view as if it does. But the user defaults will then get written out after that. Up to several seconds after.  Same when they hit the home button.

The documentation completely explains the app life cycle. Use the messages. And you should force flush out the defaults when these messages are received.  Put in your initialization or ViewDidLoad like this:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movingToBackground:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movingToForeground:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateDefaults:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
```

Then create the methods `movingToBackground`, `movingToForeground`, and `updateDefaults` like this:

```
-(void) updateDefaults: (NSNotification *) notification {
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Did you miss the fact that I am calling `synchronize` manually? If not, could you provide a source for "User defaults get queued to save" please? My understanding is that you can rely on the methods you propose, but calling `synchronize` is supposed to trigger an immediate write. Furthermore, do the methods you mention get called if the app crashes? How about if the user force-quits?

Comment: I didn't miss it. If you call that it will queue up to do it. If you exit(0) or hit stop in Xcode it probably won't save it out. Synchronize doesn't save it right that second.  You said if I wait 3 seconds it saves it. If I don't it doesn't. There is your answer. It's not natural in iOS for apps to quit on their own. If the user quits the app or shuts the phone down, the os quits the app when it's done saving the defaults.  It's seamless to the user.

Comment: What you're doing is like pulling the plug on the app. It's not exiting gracefully.

Comment: Again, do you have a source? This is contrary to almost everything I've ever read on persisting `NSUserDefaults`. And there are some circumstances (crashes) where 'waiting for the OS to do the right thing' might not cut it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html - the implication here is that `synchronize` should be be immediate: "At runtime, you use an NSUserDefaults object to read the defaults that your application uses from a user’s defaults database. NSUserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each time you need a default value. The synchronize method, which is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database."

Comment: I'm on mobile right now so I don't have s link to the apple docs. But the source is the apple docs and my 4.5 years experience making iOS apps. If your app crashes it might not save the defaults. If you app crashes you need to fix the crash. Not expect the iOS to behave as designed when your app doesn't. My answer is correct. I'll add the source in the docs when I can. Sorry if you don't like the answer. But your basically saying "my computer doesn't save my work if I hit save and immediately pull the plug" - yup that's going to be true.

Comment: No, I'm saying "my computer doesn't save my work if I tell it to save my work". I look forward to your reference, thanks again.

Comment: Ok down vote my answer then. Sorry. Report it as a bug.

Comment: I likely will, looks like it might be a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861142/nsuserdefaults-synchronize-not-saving-on

Comment: Check out this answer as well.  There are more discussions and answers here that lead to the fact that what you're trying to do isn't something iOS wants you doing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917106/nsuserdefaults-unreliable-in-ios-8

Comment: Thanks - those 10.10 docs describing the changes are exactly what I'm I'm looking for. PS what 'I'm trying to do' is just understand a recent change. I wouldn't propose to ship anything that does this. Thanks again for the link.

Comment: Yet you'll down vote me and not accept my answer.  I don't think this is the concept behind SO.  But ok.

Comment: My question wasn't 'please explain the intended use of nsuserdefauts'. It was 'why is this thing that always worked one way no longer doing as expected.' Your answer doesn't address that (the link in your comment does though). It instead outlines a strategy for persisting nsuserdefaults that I'm both a) already aware of and b) worked the same before and after the change. I'm sorry if your feelings are hurt.

Comment: I don't have feelings. I just believe that it's always worked the same way. Although some improper use that maybe worked before doesn't now.  That is the nature of an ever evolving os.  But we can agree to disagree on that I guess.