# Asking the user for rate weekly

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I want to ask every week, if they would like to rate the app.

So I tried to make a date which i checks if it has been passed or not and if it has passed, while it ask for rating and changed the date to (Nsdate()) plus one week:

```
 var rateDatum: NSDate {
    get {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if let date = defaults.objectForKey("rateDatum") {
            return date as! NSDate
        }else{
            let Datum = NSDate()
            Datum.dateByAddingTimeInterval(120)
            return Datum
        }
    }

    set (newValue) {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject(newValue, forKey: "rateDatum")
    }
}

// the function for checking
func checkRateDatum(){
    let components = NSDateComponents()
    components.year = 2000
    components.month = 1
    let calender = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let newDatum = calender.dateFromComponents(components)

    if rateDatum != newDatum! {
        let currentdate = NSDate()
        if currentdate.compare(rateDatum) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
            print("alert")
            let alertMotion = UIAlertController(title: "Rate?", message: "Would you mind rating the app?", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertMotion.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "5 Sterren", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){action in
                //Rederect to app's url

                })
            alertMotion.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Later", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel){action in
                //change RateDatum
                self.rateDatum = NSDate()
                self.rateDatum.dateByAddingTimeInterval(604800)
                })
            alertMotion.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Never", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){action in
                //verander datum zo dat hij niet meer wordt gezien
                self.rateDatum = newDatum!
                })
            self.presentViewController(alertMotion, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't really work, it is just really weird with checking if the date is passed.

I want it to ask it every week but only if the user is using the app.
So it would check if the date is past.
I also want the user to choose Never, so the pop-up while never come again.

Does anybody know what is wrong with my code.
Or knows a better way of handling the rate apps pop-up?

Ps. Sorry if the question isn't clear, I am not english so I find it really hard to ask a question.

Update: all code if someone needs it.

```
 var userUninterestedInRating: Bool {
        get {
            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            return defaults.boolForKey("userUninterestedInRating")
        }

        set (newvalue) {
            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            defaults.setBool(newvalue, forKey: "userUninterestedInRating")
        }
    }

var rateDatum: NSDate {
    get {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if let date = defaults.objectForKey("rateDatum") {
            return date as! NSDate
        }else{
            let Datum = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 604800)
            defaults.setObject(Datum, forKey: "rateDatum")
            return Datum
        }
    }

    set (newValue) {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject(newValue, forKey: "rateDatum")
    }
}
    func checkRateDatum(){
    if !userUninterestedInRating {
        let currentdate = NSDate()
        if currentdate.compare(rateDatum) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
            let alertMotion = UIAlertController(title: "Rate?", message: "Would you mind rating the app?", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertMotion.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "5 Sterren", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){action in
                //Rederect to app's url

                })
            alertMotion.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Later", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel){action in
                //change RateDatum
                self.rateDatum = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 604800)
                })
            alertMotion.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Never", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){action in
                //verander bool zo dat hij niet meer wordt gezien
                self.userUninterestedInRating = true
                })
            self.presentViewController(alertMotion, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to want to call `defaults.synchronize()` otherwise your data isn't going to be persisted.

Comment: That isn't true anymore @max_. Synchronize is no longer necessary.

Comment: @DanielT. As of when?

Comment: I think it was iOS 8. The documentation says, "Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes." Also you might find this SO question interesting...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861142/nsuserdefaults-synchronize-not-saving-on the existence of this issue, which is still a problem in iOS 9, shows that even when you *do* call synchronize, it doesn't save right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) This code:

```
self.rateDatum = NSDate()
self.rateDatum.dateByAddingTimeInterval(604800)
```

sets rateDatum to the current date/time. It does *not* add anything to rateDatum. Note that `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` returns a *new* NSDate object.

Better would be:

```
rateDatum = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 604800)
```

2) It isn't appropriate to compare dates using `!=` unless you have overloaded the operator to work for NSDates. You need to compare them using compare.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. And what is a overloaded operator

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to compare rateDatum to Jan, 2000 in the first place. As for your question about overloading operators... Check out https://www.raywenderlich.com/80818/operator-overloading-in-swift-tutorial

Comment: That is for the option never

Comment: Oh, okay... I would just have a Bool called something like `userUninterestedInRating`. If it's true, then don't ask them to rate.

Comment: Okay, I will do that.

Comment: Like this? Watch question

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: Btw Does the get{} function with Nsuserdefaults only get called when the view loaded or every time when viewDidappear happens?