# How do I use NSUserDefaults in Swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm new to Swift and I was wondering how I use `NSUserDefaults`. when save the data it looks to save but when I call it it doesn't load the data

For example:

```
defaults.setObject(nice, forKey: "nicer")
```

and when I call it, it will not load any of the data in it.

Comment: Please share how you load the data.

Comment: Here is easiest explanation : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMIx7H4u4lg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to stack overflow! you want to sync them. for example:

```
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: From method documentation: `this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.`

Comment: And `synchronize()` never worked properly in the first place. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861142/nsuserdefaults-synchronize-not-saving-on

Comment: actually the synchronized was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I usually use UserDefaults in Swift, some steps are optional or versatile depend on your application.

```
// creates an easy reference to user defaults it is optional 
    let container = UserDefaults.standard
//You can use some variable like that or enum 
    let valueToStore : String = "Persist some value"
//how I set information to the key
    container.set("New persisted data", forKey: valueToStore)
//how I retrieve information from the defaults for a key
    container.value(forKey: valueToStore)
```

Comment: or you can just make those easier and do the 'UserDefualts.standard.set' not hard to do lol but thanks for the help

Comment: also didn't really answer my question... thanks though.